# LocationManager crash when app wakes for update

Tags: ios, swift, crash, cllocationmanager

Although it works normal when app is active, it crashes when app is terminated and wakes for location update

My code to handle app wakes up for location update on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var glat : String = ""
    var glong : String = ""

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager() //or without this line, both crashes
                    locationManager.delegate = self
                    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
                    if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways) {
                        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                    }
                }
return true
    }
```

Here is the locationmanager delegate on AppDelegate

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if  let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
                let long = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude {
                print(glat + " " + glong)

                glat = String(lat)
                glong = String(long)

                //Line 339
                updateloc(String(lat), long: String(long))
            }
    }
```

Function to send location info to server

```
func updateloc(lat : String, long : String) {

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        //Line 354
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "URLTO/updateloc.php")!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let data = "lat=\(lat)&long=\(long)"
        request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let response = response {

                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                    {
                        do{
                            let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())

                            var success = 0


                            if let dictJSON = resultJSON as? [String:AnyObject] {
                                if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                                    success = successInteger

                                    if success == 1
                                    {
                                    print("ok")
                                    }


                                } else {
                                    print("no 'success' key in the dictionary, or 'success' was not compatible with Int")
                                }
                            } else {
                                print("unknown JSON problem")
                            }


                        } catch _{
                            print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
                        }

                    }
                })
            }
        })
        task.resume()


    }
```

Here is the crash log

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0                          0x10015d998 specialized AppDelegate.updateloc(String, long : String) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:354)
1                          0x10015ddf8 specialized AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:339)
2                          0x100159d0c @objc AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift)
3  CoreLocation                   0x1893d08b8 (null) + 21836
4  CoreLocation                   0x1893ccaac (null) + 5952
5  CoreLocation                   0x1893c6e48 (null) + 880
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18262cf84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18262c8bc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 308
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18262ad04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1960
9  CoreFoundation                 0x182554c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
10 GraphicsServices               0x183e3c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11 UIKit                          0x18783e088 UIApplicationMain + 204
12                         0x10015a324 main (AppDelegate.swift:20)
```

App crashes when app wakes for a location update in `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` mode

I really can't see any mistake here. Anyone can help me to fix it ?

Comment: Why are you calling `updateloc(String(lat), long: String(long))` when you have the Strings `glat` and `glong`?  Is it possible that the String constructor is returning `nil`?  Also do you know which line the crash is occurring at exactly?

Comment: But same function works well when the app is foreground ? Yes i showed the lines in the code.

Comment: I see CoreLocation is (null) in the crash log, what does that mean?

Comment: In documentation is written: When app becomes awake then you have small amount of time (it is depending on OS version) to execute some staff. Can it be that location upload takes more time that OS is giving. And for this reason it is killing your app. You can try to do upload using background task.

Comment: @Ramis can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have time to write code for you. I did quick search how to enable background stuff for NSURLSession and it is here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started . Scroll to "Enabling Background Transfers".

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, I would suggest moving your location manager functionality to a separate class, and having your location class subscribe to the UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification notification to handle what happens when the app is restarted.

A way to do this would be to have your class a Singleton and have it relay the location updates through the NSNotificationCenter.

startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges will wake up your app in the background if its enabled when the app gets terminated by the OS.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could subscribe to two different events and start stop the relevant location services base on the app delegate events.

As a broad (shot in the dark) example:

```
class LocationCommander {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let defaultCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    //- NSUserDefaults - LocationServicesControl_KEY to be set to TRUE when user has enabled location services.
    let UserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let LocationServicesControl_KEY = "LocationServices"

    init(){
        defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.appWillTerminate), name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil)
        defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.appIsRelaunched), name: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func appIsRelaunched (notification: NSNotification) {

        //- Stops Significant Location Changes services when app is relaunched
        self.locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        let ServicesEnabled = self.UserDefaults.boolForKey(self.LocationServicesControl_KEY)

        //- Re-Starts Standard Location Services if they have been enabled by the user
        if (ServicesEnabled) {
            self.updateLocation()
        }
    }

    func appWillTerminate (notification: NSNotification){

        let ServicesEnabled = self.UserDefaults.boolForKey(self.LocationServicesControl_KEY)

        //- Stops Standard Location Services if they have been enabled
        if ServicesEnabled {

            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            //- Start Significant Location Changes to restart the app
            self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func updateLocation () {

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized){

            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone

            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            //- Save Location Services ENABLED to NSUserDefaults
            self.UserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: self.LocationServicesControl_KEY)
        } else {
            //- Unauthorized, requests permissions
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this code has not been tested, I've extracted segments of an old project which might have some syntax errors due to the updates to the language.

Overall we are doing this:

- Subscribe to relevant notifications
- When app is about to terminate, check if we are getting location updates, if we are, stop the standard service and start the significant changes service to wake up the app when a new update is available.
- When the app wakes up, it will notify the class which will decide if we continue to track notification updates or not (Based on a value stored on NSUserDefaults).

Your app might be crashing due to instantiating a new location manager which then tries to restart location services that might already be running.

I hope this helps!

Comment: As far as i know it is not needed to enable background location updates in order to make SignificantLocationChanges work when app terminated?

Comment: Skimming through the documentation it seems you are right, however the documentation mentions that "At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data" - Which might require background location updates to be enabled to allow the app to restart location services while in the background.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says

> For services that relaunch the app, the system adds the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key to the options dictionary passed to the app delegate at launch time. When this key is present, you should restart your app’s location services right away. The options dictionary does not include information about the location event itself. You must configure a new location manager object and delegate and start your location services again to receive any pending events.

Furthermore it says:

> Calling this method [means `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`] several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this method.

This implies more than might be clear on first glance. First, the fact that a location update triggered your app's **relaunch** doesn't mean you immediately get it via the delegate's `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method. Second, if you are in **background** (and thus not relaunched, but just became active!), things *are yet different again*. In fact, a common problem I've seen people encounter is that they don't know whether they're in background (inactive) or terminated/just relaunched. You can't even easily test/see this, because an app that was terminated by the system still shows up when pressing the home button twice. Check the list shown under `Attach to Process...` in XCode's `Debug` menu to see whether your app is still running (and in background) or not (btw, terminating an app via the Stop button in XCode results in this inconsistency if you wanna play around with the various ways you can become active or relaunched). I just mention this here because a lot of questions ask "How come X happens when my app gets active again?" and the people answering assume different things than what the asking person meant by that.

Anyways, if your App was in fact relaunched, your `locationManager` variable contains a brand new instance now, and you should get an update right after calling `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. I'll get to the problem you might still encounter then below.
If your App just became active again, you should call `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, then `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` again to get an update immediately (in short: always stop then start to properly restart, it doesn't hurt even if you weren't running already).

Now to the problem I think that results (in part) from this mess with Apple's way of relaunching after location updates. I'm not entirely sure what's happening without playing around with your code, but I hope this is of some help:
In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method you set a local constant with `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`. *This* one then is restarted and triggers location updates. However, it *might* get deallocated before the delegate's `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method is called, after all, the callback happens asynchronously (and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` might return before that is called). I have no idea how or why this even works and gets as far as you say it does, maybe it's luck, or it has to do with how CLLocationManager internally works. Anyways, what I *think* then happens is that in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, you don't get meaningful location data anymore, because the `CLLocationManager` instance responsible for the call is not valid anymore. `lat` and `long` are empty or even nil and your request's URL (which you haven't shown) is invalid.

I would suggest to first:

1. Ensure that your class's constant `locationManager` is properly set in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (right after you checked the presence of the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` flag). Get rid of the local constant of the same name.
2. Stop and then restart the location updates. This should call your delegate's `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method immediately with the latest location data (the one that triggered your app's relaunch or becoming active again).
3. Ensure you get meaningful data in your `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method. Don't call `updateloc` if that's not the case (you might also want to move the line `print(glat + " " + glong)` to after you set the class's variables to the new values, so you see on the console whether what you get makes sense).

There"s one small thing I can't tell on the top of my head: If your app is just getting active again (and not relaunched) I'm not sure whether the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` is even set at all. You might wanna investigate that one, too. If becoming active isn't a "relaunch" in that sense, though, your `locationManager` should still be happy an working anyways, at least that's what I get from the documentation (and it's been a while since I've tried that myself). Let me/us know if you're still having problems, I'm curious how it'll turn out. :)

Comment: is there a way to get location without using delegate? i think i remember sth like location property also filled with location info when app wakes?

Comment: I've never used it, but yes, the documentation claims you can get the latest one from `locationManager.location`, if memory serves right. You might have to start the tracking for that, though, I'm not sure and can't check atm. However, be sure to check what you pass to your `updateloc` method. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT.rawValue), 0)) {
          updateloc(String(lat), long: String(long))   
}
```